# Java Gradle Gen Sources

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft-fabric

Hi there I want to know what java I need to have for gradle to not fail during .\gradle gensources . I remember there being a specific version of java for this and I forgot the link can somebody comment it?

I tried just downloading java 17 and it didn't work

Comment: Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How did it not work? Do you get an error message? It sounds like your Java may not be installed properly, can you run `.\gradlew --version` and make sure that works before running a particular task?

Comment: Hi there Bernie this is what came up Build time:   2022-08-05 21:17:56 UTC
Revision:     d1daa0cbf1a0103000b71484e1dbfe096e095918

Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.5 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.5+9-LTS-191)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64